# Make an option selected in a select in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

In a blade template I have various selects.

I get a type id from a database, on each option I check if the value of the option is equal to the value from the database, if so, set as selected.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Please note, I cannot loop through the options as these are statically coded and do not exists in an array (and I do not want them in an array).

```
 <select name="type-id">
    <option value="1" {{ $data->type_id === 1 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Type 1</option>
    <option value="2" {{ $data->type_id === 2 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Type 2</option>
```

Comment: Are the fields in the form related to existing data in the DB? As in, is the form for updating an existing record?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some javascript to do that.
I wouldn't recommend it, though. Looping seems way much cleaner.

```js
var selector = 'select[name=type-id] > option[value="{{ $data->type_id }}"]';
var option;

if (null !== (option = document.querySelector(selector)))
  option.selected = true;
```